# displaying minus in grid extjs. displaying only NOT CHANGE the value to minus

Tags: extjs

i'm new comer in ext js..
i want to display one of field in grid ext js. the field type is smallint. let's say it "Dayfrom". I want to display DayFrom in Grid like (-3) days in minus without calculate the value. only display in grid.

i have try to for this. but not work

```
var s = Ext.String.format('<div class="{0}">{1}</div>','-','--');

storePendingApprovalDetail = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'pendingapprovaldetail-store',
    model: 'pendingapprovaldetail-model',
    sorters: ['DayFrom']
});
gridPendingApprovalDetail = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: 'pendingapprovaldetail-store',
    columns: [{
        text: 'Day From',
        flex: 1,
        renderer: s,
        dataIndex: 'DayFrom'
    }, {
        text: 'Day To',
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'DayTo'
    }, {
        text: 'Frequent',
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'Frequent'
    }],
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [actAddPendingApprovalDetail, actEditPendingApprovalDetail, actDeletePendingApprovalDetail]
    }],
    listeners: {
    }
});
```

Comment: Use a column renderer.

Comment: thanks dude, you are right. it works on me.. i just don't know what is the best keyword to find this case coz i'm really new comer in extjs haha..many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the renderer example at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer ?

Do you actually know what `Ext.String.format` does? If not, please read http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.String-method-format

If you had done so, and understood, your code for the renderer would be sth like this:

```
renderer: function(value){
    if(typeof value=="number") return -value;
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

many thanks buddies...  :)

i'm using this and it works

```
gridPendingApprovalDetail = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: 'pendingapprovaldetail-store',
    columns: [{
        text: 'Day From',
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'DayFrom', renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
            var returnString = "-" + value;
            return returnString;
        }
    }, {
        text: 'Day To',
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'DayTo'
    }, {
        text: 'Frequent',
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'Frequent'
    }],
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [actAddPendingApprovalDetail, actEditPendingApprovalDetail, actDeletePendingApprovalDetail]
    }],
    listeners: {
    }
});
```